# How to get the y value on the pointed curve according x value from mouse movement

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, events, plot

I have a Python script in which I import some sensor data taken each x milliseconds.
I plot these values using tkinter and matplotlib.
I also use "MultiCursor" from Matplotlib to have a line through all subplots following the mouse.
What I want now is to be able to display beside of each subplot, the value on y corresponding to the current x value of the cursor.

I have made some research and unfortunately I don't know how to proceed. I analyzed methods from matplotlib event, from matplotlib axis, but I have found nothing.

I already know that one of the problems will be that my data are discrete measures and not a continuous set of values, but as the plot is a continues line, is there not any way to get the value from the axis directly?

Herebelow the minimal code I have for now, but there is not any try about this specific request.

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

w_main = tk.Tk()
w_main.geometry("1080x720")
f_leftFrame = tk.Frame(w_main)
f_leftFrame.pack(side=tk.LEFT, anchor='nw', fill=tk.BOTH)
f_graphFrame = tk.Frame(w_main)
f_graphFrame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)
graph = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=f_graphFrame)
graph.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

time = [0, 0.150, 0.3, 0.450, 0.6, 0.750, 0.9]
record1 = [0, 5, 3, 6, 2, 8, 9]
record2 = [1, 6, 8, 5, 7, 2, 5]
record3 = [9, 7, 5, 3, 0, 0, 2]
liste = []

for i in range(3):
    globals()["ax{}".format(i)] = fig.add_subplot(int("31{}".format(i+1)))
    liste.append(globals()["ax{}".format(i)])

for i in range(len(liste)):
    liste[i].plot(time, globals()["record{}".format(i+1)])

multi = MultiCursor(graph, liste, 'r', lw=2.0, vertOn=True)

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Maybe this approach works for you? [How to have a fast crosshair mouse cursor for subplots in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63195460/how-to-have-a-fast-crosshair-mouse-cursor-for-subplots-in-matplotlib/63197021#63197021)

Comment: It is exactly what I was looking for, I would just prefered if it had been possible with MultiCursors from Matplotlib but anyway.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally succeeded in making it working without mplcursor but with MultiCursor from Matplotlib.Thanks to @JohanC, I got inspired from the code in the link he gave.

Here below the minimal code (maybe not coded with the best way to do it but working):

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.widgets import MultiCursor
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

w_main = tk.Tk()
w_main.geometry("1080x720")
f_leftFrame = tk.Frame(w_main)
f_leftFrame.pack(side=tk.LEFT, anchor='nw', fill=tk.BOTH)
f_graphFrame = tk.Frame(w_main)
f_graphFrame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)
graph = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=f_graphFrame)
graph.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

time = [0, 0.150, 0.3, 0.450, 0.6, 0.750, 0.9]
record1 = [0, 5, 3, 6, 2, 8, 9]
record2 = [1, 6, 8, 5, 7, 2, 5]
record3 = [9, 7, 5, 3, 0, 0, 2]
liste = []

for i in range(3):
    globals()["ax{}".format(i)] = fig.add_subplot(int("31{}".format(i+1)))
    liste.append(globals()["ax{}".format(i)])

for i in range(len(liste)):
    liste[i].plot(time, globals()["record{}".format(i+1)])

for i in range(len(liste)):
    globals()["plot{}".format(i)], = liste[i].plot(time, globals()["record{}".format(i+1)])

def displayXY(event):
    y0 = np.interp(event.xdata, plot0.get_xdata(), plot0.get_ydata())
    y1 = np.interp(event.xdata, plot1.get_xdata(), plot1.get_ydata())
    y2 = np.interp(event.xdata, plot2.get_xdata(), plot2.get_ydata())
    print("y0 = {}, y1 = {}, y2 = {}".format(round(y0, 2), round(y1, 2), round(y2, 2)))

multi = MultiCursor(graph, liste, 'r', lw=2.0, vertOn=True)
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', displayXY)

tk.mainloop()
```