# How do I make the default matplotlib cursor '+' span the entire x-axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib

As default, the matplotlib cursor that is see is a small '+' sign. How can I make it stretched so that it is long both along the x-axes as well as the y-axes? As an example, I am reffering to the dashed lines in the following figure:

[image]

So far I have tried:

```
  from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor
  curr = Cursor(axt, color='r', lw=.5, horizOn=True, vertOn=True)
```

But its very slow. I also tried `useblit=True` but that was even slower. Also the cursor vanishes if I zoom.So what I am looking for is a way to change the default cursor.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no native option for a crosshair cursor. Nonetheless, this is a reasonable (and quite common) request. It even made its way into the matplotlib-(developer)-docs [here](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/misc/cursor_demo.html) and the corresponding demo [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/gallery/misc/cursor_demo_sgskip.html). The approach is similar to the one you took: redrawing the figure every time the cursor is moved. For a smooth behavior, this unfortunately requires some calculation power as it need to run at 25Hz to 60Hz (0.017ms).

There the posts also refer to the third-party implementations [`mpldatacursor`](https://github.com/joferkington/mpldatacursor) and [`mplcursors`](https://github.com/anntzer/mplcursors) for out-of-the-box implementations. This is the same that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63195460/how-to-have-a-fast-crosshair-mouse-cursor-for-subplots-in-matplotlib) stackoverflow post points two.